# OpenGL error 0x0500 in -[CCParticleSystemQuad draw] 455

Tags: ios, iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, ccparticlesystem

I am developing box2d game. In that i used animations and particle effect, My game is working fine but console i am getting this error continually.

```
OpenGL error 0x0500 in -[CCParticleSystemQuad draw] 455
OpenGL error 0x0500 in -[CCParticleSystemQuad draw] 455
OpenGL error 0x0500 in -[CCParticleSystemQuad draw] 455
OpenGL error 0x0500 in -[CCParticleSystemQuad draw] 455
OpenGL error 0x0500 in -[CCParticleSystemQuad draw] 455
OpenGL error 0x0500 in -[CCParticleSystemQuad draw] 455
OpenGL error 0x0500 in -[CCParticleSystemQuad draw] 455
```

Present i am using cocos2d V2.1. Can any one tell me, what is error? Why this happen?

Thanks...